# Trying to sort two arrays based on distance from origin

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two arrays that are created from user inputs.

> 

```
n = int(input("How many coordinates would you like to enter:"))
myArray1 = [None] * n
myArray2 = [None] * n

for i in range(len(myArray1)):
    x = int(input("Enter X:"))
    y = int(input("Enter Y:"))
    myArray1[i] = x
    myArray2[i] = y
```

I want the parallel values from each array to be used to find their distance from origin by using math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2). Once the distance value is found, it will be used to sort the two parallel list values. I am struggling with this because I am unsure how to sort two separate arrays, and then display them as an ordered pair in order of their distance from origin.

I am new to python so any advice or general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact they come from user input is unimportant. Just say you have 2 arrays. See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: `zip(*arrays)` can be used to tie two datasets together, or you could nest lists as you create them `my_array.append([x, y])` or rather you could calculate the distance as soon as it's given and store that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` builtin and pass a lambda function to key argument to sort the index based on the values of distances d, finally use this index list to form the result:

Data:

```py
n=5
arr1
[0, 9, -6, -2, -9]
arr2
[8, -2, 6, -3, 6]
d = [(x**2+y**2)**0.5 for x,y in zip(arr1,arr2)]
[8.0, 9.219544457292887, 8.48528137423857, 3.605551275463989, 10.816653826391969]
```

Logic:

```py
sorted_indices=sorted(range(n), key=lambda i:d[i])
outX,outY,outD=[],[],[]
for i in sorted_indices:
    outX.append(arr1[i])
    outY.append(arr2[i])
    outD.append(d[i])
```

OUTPUT:

```py
outX
[-2, 0, -6, 9, -9]
outY
[-3, 8, 6, -2, 6]
outD
[3.605551275463989, 8.0, 8.48528137423857, 9.219544457292887, 10.816653826391969]
```